# How to find the difference between time and feed the difference in a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, feature-engineering

I have a dataframe **trades_df** which looks like this -

| Open Time | Open Price | Close Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19-08-2020 12:19 | 1.19459 | 19-08-2020 12:48 |
| 28-08-2020 03:09 | 0.90157 | 08-09-2020 12:20 |

It has columns **open_time** and **close_time** in the format **19-08-2020 12:19**. I want to make a new column 'time_spent' which would be the difference between 'close_time' and 'open_time'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Start_Time' : ['19-08-2020 12:19', '28-08-2020 03:09'],
    'End_Time' : ['19-08-2020 12:48', '28-08-2020 06:03']
})

df['Start_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_Time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['End_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['End_Time'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df['Time_Difference'] = df['End_Time'] - df['Start_Time']
df
```

Comment: Yes, but you have made a new data frame, I wanted the difference to be in the same data frame as a new column.

Comment: Just change `df` from my code to whatever you named your dataframe. As well as `df['Time_Difference']` will create a new column so long as there isn't a Time_Difference column already in your dataframe

Answer (score 1):

Your datetimes have days come first, so `dayfirst` should be True:

```py
# use dayfirst argument to convert to correct datetimes
df['time_spent'] = pd.to_datetime(df.close_time, dayfirst=True) - pd.to_datetime(df.open_time, dayfirst=True)
```